# Angular, observable subscribing to promise

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, observable

I'm learning Angular from `angular.io` and I think I have pretty good grasp on Observables and Promises (yes I know they are not Angular specific).

However in the examples I have found something that confuses me.

So not to copy/paste everything; we have `HeroService` service class

One of the methods is this:

```
getHero(id: number | string) {
     return heroesPromise
     .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === +id));
}
```

No issues there, method uses `heroesPromise` calls `then` which returns `Promise<Hero>`.
So bottom line `getHero()` returns Promise.

Second component uses this `HeroService` in variable named `service`.
This is the code in other component which confuses me:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
    // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
   .switchMap((params: Params) => this.service.getHero(+params['id']))
   .subscribe((hero: Hero) => this.hero = hero);
}
```

So what I'm confused is this part within `switchMap()` callback:

```
this.service.getHero(+params['id'])
```

This obviously returns `Promise<Hero>` because that is what `getHero()` returns.

But then inner Observable's (created by `switchMap`) `subscribe()` method looks like this:

```
subscribe((hero: Hero) => this.hero = hero)
```

As you can see callback of `subscribe()` takes `Hero`, not `Promise<Hero>` which is what callback of `switchMap()` returns.

Why is that, any thoughts?

Comment: You use `subscribe` on observables to execute them and the response will be their value.  `switchMap` returns an observable. So you are subscribing to the observable that `switchMap` returns. I don't see the problem here.

Comment: I'm talking about parameter of the type `Hero` that callback of `subscribe()` takes, not the `subscribe()` itself. I know that `switchMap()` returns observable which then subscribes on.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be of type `Hero`? `getHero(id)` returns `Promise<Hero>` as you said and when `subscribe` resolves this `Promise` it will have `Hero` as its parameter. Its almost the same as `getHero(id)` methods `then` callback

Comment: Well that was my question. Does observable `subscribe()` method automatically behind the scenes resolves `Promise` in it's callback? I couldn't find any documentation about it.

Comment: `subscribe()` is `Promise`s `then()` for `Observables`

Comment: Lets say that callback of `switchMap()` returns `int`. Than it would look like this: `.subscribe((dummy: int) => { <some code> })`. But callback of `switchMap()` returns `Promise<Hero>` and callback  of `subscribe()` takes `Hero`.

Comment: If the callback of `switchMap` returned `int` you wouldn't needed the `switchMap` in the first place. `switchMap` always returns an observable https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Comment: After reading some more I see what you are talking about. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that Promise and Observable are "just" wrappers for callbacks. When you chain `then()`s in Promise chain or use operators with Observable chains you are passing **function** or a **value** from one callback to the next.

Consider this fake code:

```
const fn = (something) => { return other(something); }

Observable.from([1, 2, 3])
  .map(o => fn(o))
  .swithMap(o => Promise.resolve(o => fn(o)))
  .swithMap(o => Observable.of(o => fn(o)))
```

You use `switchMap()` to get a **value** from some wrapped callback asynchronously (either from Promise, or Observable). `map()` is a synchronous operator and you are dealing with values directly.

If you want more details about how things work, watch this awesome talk by André Staltz, and [You will learn RxJS](https://youtu.be/uQ1zhJHclvs).

Comment: That is what confused me, I thought that `swithMap()` callback also works with values directly but it turns out that `switchMap()` callback has to return `ObservableInput`. And `ObservableInput` (extends `SubscribableOrPromise`)  describes Observables, Promises and "any collection of values that can be transformed to Observable".